# Merge two Pandas Dataframes based on two IDs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two tables, one is called 'result_df':

| tourney_name | tourney_year | tourney_month | tourney_day | player1_id | player2_id | predicted_outcome | predicted_probability | actual_outcome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2024 | 1 | 1 | 1001 | 1002 | 0 | 0.028771 | 0 |
| 3 | 2024 | 1 | 1 | 1007 | 1008 | 1 | 0.647801 | 1 |
| 3 | 2024 | 1 | 1 | 1013 | 1014 | 1 | 0.652244 | 1 |

And the other one is called 'betting_lines_24':

| winner_id | winner_name | loser_name | loser_id | B365W | B365L | tourney_year | tourney_month | tourney_day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1013 | Dimitrov G. | Murray A. | 1014 | 1.33 | 3.40 | 2024 | 1 | 1 |
| 1001 | Safiullin R. | Shelton B. | 1002 | 2.30 | 1.62 | 2024 | 1 | 1 |
| 1007 | Rune H. | Purcell M. | 1008 | 1.25 | 4.00 | 2024 | 1 | 1 |

And now I need to merge them, so that the resulting table will be like 'result_df', but adding the name of each player (based on the IDs) and also the betting lines for each player. The resulting dataframe should be something like this:

| tourney_name | tourney_year | tourney_month | tourney_day | player1_id | player1_name | player2_name | player2_id | B365W | B365L | predicted_probability | predicted_outcome | actual_outcome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2024 | 1 | 1 | 1002 | Shelton B. | Safiullin R. | 1001 | 1.62 | 2.30 | 0.028771 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 2024 | 1 | 1 | 1007 | Rune H. | Purcell M. | 1008 | 1.25 | 4.00 | 0.647801 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2024 | 1 | 1 | 1013 | Dimitrov G. | Murray A. | 1014 | 1.33 | 3.40 | 0.652244 | 1 | 1 |

The IDs in one 'result_df' may be shuffled on the 'betting_lines_24', not always the player1_id equals to the winner_id, it may happen that player1_id is in the loser_id column in the 'betting_lines_24' dataframe.
Also the matches in 'result_df' are not in the same order as in 'betting_lines_24'.

How could i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

```
col1 = ['player1_id', 'player1_name', 'player2_name', 'player2_id', 'B365W', 'B365L', 'tourney_year', 'tourney_month', 'tourney_day']
col2 = ['player2_id', 'player2_name', 'player1_name', 'player1_id', 'B365L', 'B365W', 'tourney_year', 'tourney_month', 'tourney_day']
tmp = pd.concat([betting_lines_24.set_axis(col1, axis=1), betting_lines_24.set_axis(col2, axis=1)])
col3 = ['tourney_name', 'tourney_year', 'tourney_month', 'tourney_day', 'player1_id', 'player1_name', 
        'player2_name', 'player2_id', 'B365W', 'B365L', 'predicted_probability', 'predicted_outcome',
        'actual_outcome']
out = result_df.merge(tmp, how='left')[col3]
```

out

```
   tourney_name  tourney_year  tourney_month  tourney_day  player1_id  \
0             3          2024              1            1        1001   
1             3          2024              1            1        1007   
2             3          2024              1            1        1013   

   player1_name player2_name  player2_id  B365W  B365L  predicted_probability  \
0  Safiullin R.   Shelton B.        1002   2.30   1.62               0.028771   
1       Rune H.   Purcell M.        1008   1.25   4.00               0.647801   
2   Dimitrov G.    Murray A.        1014   1.33   3.40               0.652244   

   predicted_outcome  actual_outcome  
0                  0               0  
1                  1               1  
2                  1               1
```

plz read notification before ask question : [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 4):

```
betting_lines_v1 = betting_lines_24.rename(columns={'winner_id': 'player1_id', 'loser_id': 'player2_id', 'winner_name': 'player1_name', 'loser_name': 'player2_name'})
betting_lines_v2 = betting_lines_24.rename(columns={'winner_id': 'player2_id', 'loser_id': 'player1_id', 'winner_name': 'player2_name', 'loser_name': 'player1_name'})
merged_v1 = pd.merge(result_df, betting_lines_v1, on=['player1_id', 'player2_id', 'tourney_year', 'tourney_month', 'tourney_day'], how='left')
merged_v2 = pd.merge(result_df, betting_lines_v2, on=['player1_id', 'player2_id', 'tourney_year', 'tourney_month', 'tourney_day'], how='left')
final_df = pd.concat([merged_v1, merged_v2]).drop_duplicates(subset=['tourney_name', 'tourney_year', 'tourney_month', 'tourney_day', 'player1_id', 'player2_id'])
final_df = final_df.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
final_df = final_df[['tourney_name', 'tourney_year', 'tourney_month', 'tourney_day', 'player1_id', 'player1_name', 'player2_name', 'player2_id', 'B365W', 'B365L', 'predicted_probability', 'predicted_outcome', 'actual_outcome']]

final_df
```

Output:

```
   tourney_name  tourney_year  tourney_month  tourney_day  player1_id  \
0             3          2024              1            1        1001   
1             3          2024              1            1        1007   
2             3          2024              1            1        1013   

   player1_name player2_name  player2_id  B365W  B365L  predicted_probability  \
0  Safiullin R.   Shelton B.        1002   2.30   1.62               0.028771   
1       Rune H.   Purcell M.        1008   1.25   4.00               0.647801   
2   Dimitrov G.    Murray A.        1014   1.33   3.40               0.652244   

   predicted_outcome  actual_outcome  
0                  0               0  
1                  1               1  
2                  1               1
```

The drop Nan is there to take out the unwanted values. Using similar naming convention we get help in swapping.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works but not for all the data in the DataFrame. I believe it works when player1_id = winner_id and player2_id = loser_id, but not in the rows where player1_id = loser_id, player2_id = winner_id. I would need to check both cases as there are some rows in the result_df that have some id shuffled.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to merge two DataFrames. You could do this simply with:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="ID")
```

Which you could do based on either a player ID, a specific match ID or on the winner ID. That depends on what you prefer.

You just need to make sure that this column with ID's is shared between the two dataframes.

For example, based on a newly made variable match ID:

```
df1["matchid"] = str(df1.player1_id)+str(df1.player2_id)
df2["matchid"] = str(df1.player1_id)+str(df1.player2_id)
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="matchid")
```

Next time, it could help to phrase your question in the simplest way possible. Using the example from [this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-two-pandas-dataframes-by-matched-id-number/), e.g.;

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8],  
                    'Name': ['Sam', 'John', 'Bridge', 
                             'Edge', 'Joe', 'Hope']}) 
  
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9], 
                    'Marks': [67, 92, 75, 83, 69, 56, 81]})
```

Comment: The IDs are shared in both dataframes. The thing is in one it is in the player1_id and player2_id columns and in the other it is in winner_id and loser_id. But they are not always in the same order, as sometimes the ID for player1_id is in the winner_id column and sometimes is in the loser_id column.

Comment: You can still create a unique match-id based on the information in both dataframes, including dates for example. If you the merge the dfs you have all information in a single df, including player id, name and winner/loser id.